# Shopify XML Post in PHP

Tags: shopify

I am having trouble posting XML data using PHP and Curl to Shopify. I have:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><variant><id type="integer">260293006</id><fulfillment-service>manual</fulfillment-service><inventory-management>shopify</inventory-management><inventory-policy>deny</inventory-policy><sku>s136</sku><inventory-quantity type="integer">48</inventory-quantity><price>17.95</price></variant>';
$url = 'https://' . $API_KEY . ':' . $PASSWORD . '@' . $STORE_URL . '/admin/variants/#260293006.xml';
```

My code is:

```
$session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
echo $response;
curl_close($session);
```

What is returned by Shopify page with this title:

```
<title>Shopify &raquo; Please Log In</title>
```

I think I am probably missing something obvious. Once I get this function to work, everything else should be easy to build. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Based on this feedback, I was able to solve the problem. Major issues:

1. The # is not needed as user-457786 suggested
2. It needs to be a PUT method, not POST, which I found based on user-457786's link
3. A few other changes to the CURL:

   ```
   $fp = tmpfile();
   fwrite($fp, $xml);
   fseek($fp, 0); 
   $session = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
   curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp); // file pointer
   curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($xml));   
   curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
   $response = curl_exec($session);
   fclose($fp);
   curl_close($session);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I think `#` is not needed in `$url`, It should be

```
$url = 'https://' . $API_KEY . ':' . $PASSWORD . '@' . $STORE_URL . '/admin/variants/260293006.xml';
```

Comment: I think this is some progress. Now Shopify returns:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hash>
    <errors>Not Found</errors>
    </hash>

Comment: Make sure your variant-id is proper. Btw what  action do you want to perform on 'Variants'? Here is a good documentation for [Product Variant](http://wiki.shopify.com/Product_Variant_%28API%29)